# Open Notification Center programmatically on OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite, notificationcenter

Is there a way to open Notification Center on OS X from a Cocoa app?
We tried launching the Notification Center app, but that doesn't work.
Our app is not sandboxed, so we can do whatever is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can open it using ScriptingBridge, but it's not an official API, so it might break someday.
It's a bit odd, but this **only works with sandboxed apps**. If your app is not sandboxed, you need Accessibility access.

### 1. Generate Header file

Open Terminal and run the following commands:

```
cd ~/Desktop/
sdef /System/Library/CoreServices/System\ Events.app | sdp -fh --basename SystemEvents
```

Copy the file "SystemEvents.h" from your Desktop into your project.
Xcode will show some errors or warnings for a few lines in this file. Just remove these lines.

### 2. Import ScriptingBridge framework and generated header file.

```
#import <ScriptingBridge/ScriptingBridge.h>
```

and

```
#import "SystemEvents.h"
```

### 3. Add code

```
SystemEventsApplication *systemEventsApp = (SystemEventsApplication *)[[SBApplication alloc] initWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.systemevents"];
SystemEventsApplicationProcess *sysUIServer = [systemEventsApp.applicationProcesses objectWithName:@"SystemUIServer"];

SystemEventsMenuBarItem *item = nil;
for (SystemEventsMenuBar *menuBar in sysUIServer.menuBars) {
    item = [menuBar.menuBarItems objectWithName:@"Notification Center"];
    if (item != nil && [item.name isEqualToString:@"Notification Center"])
        break;
}

[item clickAt:nil];
```

You can also replace line 4-9 with this code, if you're sure the menu bars won't change in the future:

```
SystemEventsMenuBarItem *item = [[[sysUIServer.menuBars objectAtLocation:@2] menuBarItems] objectWithName:@"Notification Center"];
```

### 4. Add temporary exception for sandbox

Open your projects .entitlements file and add "com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events" as an array. Add "com.apple.systemevents" as String.

---

### Switching to Today view

This requires your app to have Accessibility access, so it won't work in sandboxed apps. You can simply call this script instead of using ScriptingBridge:

```
tell application "System Events"
    click menu bar item "Notification Center" of menu bar 2 of application process "SystemUIServer"
    click radio button "Today" of radio group 1 of window "NotificationTableWindow" of application process "NotificationCenter"
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately there is no support for opening the Notification Center.  Supposedly because it wouldn't be annoying for the user to have it open without them wanting it to open